# Fix axes and column bar in a facet_wrap ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis, facet-wrap

Hi there I'm having some struggle with an R plot. I begin saying what I'm doing is probably not conventional (or recommended, I guess); however, I'm trying to plot three *metrics* for four different samples based on a combination of experiments.

Now, of them – the precision – happens to a way smaller value than the other and, for this reason is not visible in the plot nor someone can assess differences between approaches and samples. What I would normally do is adding a second y-axis, but everything is complicated by the facet_wrap...

If anyone has some ideas, or a solution to this issue, please let me know.
Something I was considering was to make a separate facets for just the precision in a sort of nested way, which I have done before, or even using a log-scale. Please, let me know what you think, thanks!

**Plot**
[image]

**Code**

```
library(grid)
library(ggh4x)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggdark)
library(ggpubr)
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(reshape2)
library(ggchicklet) #round column
library(RColorBrewer)

### HG002 and Papuan samples performance comparison, graph VS linear reference
excel_snps <- read_excel("/path/to/graph_vs_linear-reference.xlsx", 1) #SNPs 
excel_indels <- read_excel("/path/to/graph_vs_linear-reference.xlsx", 2) #INDELs
#excel_snps <- read_excel("/path/to/graph_vs_linear-reference.xlsx", 1) #SNPs macOS
#excel_indels <- read_excel("/path/to/graph_vs_linear-reference.xlsx", 2) #INDELs macOS

### Convert to dataframe
df_variants <- data.frame(excel_snps) #switch between markers
df_variants$metric <- factor(df_variants$metric, levels=c('precision', 'not_in_HPRC', 'in_HPRC')) # metrics display order

### Groups by sample
df_sample <- with(df_variants, df_variants[order(sample, approach, metric),]) # collapse metrics based on sample

# Personalize strips in x-direction
strip <- strip_themed(background_x = elem_list_rect(fill = c("cornflowerblue", "paleturquoise", "paleturquoise", "paleturquoise")), text_x = elem_list_text(colour="black", face="bold"))

### Plot horizontal barplot for HG002 and Papuan samples comparing the performance of the graph VS the linear reference
plot <- 
  ggplot(df_variants, aes(x=sample, y=value, fill=metric)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.6, alpha=.6, color='black')
  ggplot(df_sample, aes(x=approach, y=value, fill=metric)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.6, alpha=.6, color='black') + facet_wrap2(~sample, scales='free', ncol=1, strip=strip) + theme_bw() +
  
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5), legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom', legend.direction='horizontal') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(11, "RdYlGn")[c(6, 1, 11)], labels=c('precision', 'not_in_HPRC', 'in_HPRC')) + ggtitle('Graph compared to GRCh38') + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='metric', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5)) -> export_png
export_png + coord_flip()
```

Comment: You could use a log scale `scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')` but I would recommend comparing each performance criteria within one plot so you can have a fair comparison. There would be a total of 3 plots with unique scale. It is bad habbit to mix apples and oranges

Comment: Hi @YacineHajji, thanks and noted the comment. The plot looks much better now with each metric compared across samples and approaches with appropriate scales for each one of them!